# Is there a way to not calculate a window function if the window is not full in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a window which is based on the previous day. I wish to calculate the rolling average for each row however if I don't have a complete day of data I want to return `Null`. For example

```
           dateTime group val rolling_average
2023-01-01 00:00:00     1   1            Null
2023-01-01 00:05:00     1   2            Null
2023-01-01 00:10:00     1   3            Null
2023-01-01 00:15:00     1   4            Null
...
2023-01-02 00:00:00     1   2             2.5
```

So here, for the first 4 rows, the rolling average would be `Null` since there is not a complete day within the window. However for the final row that I show, we would be able to calculate the average over the complete window. Currently, however I get the following undesired result:

```
           dateTime group val rolling_average
2023-01-01 00:00:00     1   1               1
2023-01-01 00:05:00     1   2             1.5
2023-01-01 00:10:00     1   3               2
2023-01-01 00:15:00     1   4             2.5
...
2023-01-02 00:00:00     1   2             2.5
```

I have my window set up as:

```py
window = Window.partitionBy("group").orderBy(f.col("dateTime").cast("long")).rangeBetween(-86400, 0)
```

I know that this can be done with a post-processing conditional check. I can check create a second window

```py
window = Window.partitionBy("cropseason_id").orderBy(f.col("dateTime").cast("long"))
```

and then calculate the row number and adjust the rollowing window column accordingly:

```py
(
    df
    .withColumn("rolling_average", f.avg(f.col("val")).over(window))
    .withColumn("rn", f.row_number())
    .withColumn("rolling_average", f.when(f.col("rn") < 288, f.lit(None)).otherwise(f.col("rolling_average")))
)
```

My problem with this however is that currently this dataset is 5 minute data, but it could be hourly or minute data that I use so I need a generic solution. I would have thought I can set this up in the construction of the window?

Comment: Can you explain more, what do you mean by "a complete day" ? also 2.5 should be 2.4 = 12 / 5 ?

Comment: 2.5 here is an example of what the avg would be since there are data points missing. A complete day would be 288 rows in this example (5 minute data, i.e. there are 12 5 minute intervals in an hour, so times 24 hours = 288)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can calculate time diff from first record in window and then show avg only when this diff is > than 84600, otherwise show null

It should work properly with any intervals, it will just skip anything that is not 24h older than first record in window

```
import datetime
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data = [
    (datetime.datetime.strptime("2023-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 1, 1),
    (datetime.datetime.strptime("2023-01-01 00:05:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 1, 2),
    (datetime.datetime.strptime("2023-01-01 06:05:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 1, 3),
    (datetime.datetime.strptime("2023-01-01 18:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 1, 4),
    (datetime.datetime.strptime("2023-01-02 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 1, 2),
]

myschema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("dateTime", TimestampType()),
        StructField("group", IntegerType()),
        StructField("val", IntegerType()),
    ]
)
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=myschema)

window = Window.partitionBy("group").orderBy(["dateTime"])

df = df.withColumn(
    "timeDiffFromPrevInSeconds",
    (
        (
            (F.col("dateTime")).cast("long")
            - F.first("dateTime").over(window).cast("long")
        )
    ).cast("long"),
).withColumn(
    "rolling_average",
    F.when(
        F.col("timeDiffFromPrevInSeconds") >= 86400, F.avg(F.col("val")).over(window)
    ).otherwise(None),
)

df.show()
```

Output is:

```
+-------------------+-----+---+---------------+
|           dateTime|group|val|rolling_average|
+-------------------+-----+---+---------------+
|2023-01-01 00:00:00|    1|  1|           null|
|2023-01-01 00:05:00|    1|  2|           null|
|2023-01-01 06:05:00|    1|  3|           null|
|2023-01-01 18:00:00|    1|  4|           null|
|2023-01-02 00:00:00|    1|  2|            2.4|
+-------------------+-----+---+---------------+
```

Comment: This is nice. It's actually very similar to what I eventually ended up implementing. You cannot (AFAIK) work out the max size of the window and so if you were to functionalise the above, you need to not only supply the window but the window_size.

Comment: By window size you mean to get this 86400 dynamically from outside instead of hardcoded value or you think that i should change Spark window with .range?

Comment: So the window is set by the user. But the size of the window cannot be obtained programmatically after it has been set. So if you pass the window as an argument to a function, for example, then you cannot extract the 86400 from that argument.